# Blurred view animation using GPUImage

Tags: ios, animation, blur, gpuimage

I currently try to add an blurred animation on my view for a transition. 
I'm using the `GPUImage` framework which implements the `GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter`.

It works, but the effect apply to the filter is not enough strong. I try to play with the `filter.blurRadiusInPixels` value but it seems to don't change whatever the value I try to put.

This is my code :

```
//First I init a ImageView which have the size of the frame of my view

     UIImageView * blurredArea = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

//hide this imageView for the moment

            blurredArea.alpha = 0;

 //In this part I take a snapshot of my current view that I keep in snapshot           


UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
                [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
                UIImage * snapshot=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Finally I init my GaussianFilter on my snapshot

            GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter * filter = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc] init];
            UIImage * blurred = [filter imageByFilteringImage: snapshot];

            blurredArea.image = blurred;

//Here I define the strength of the blur effect but it seems to do nothing whatever the value is putted.

            filter.blurRadiusInPixels = 1;

            [self.view addSubview:blurredArea];

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f animations:^{

//Animate the blurred imageview alpha but not enough blurred.

                blurredArea.alpha = 1;
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to do blur that looks like iOS blur in notification center (which I suggest you do), starting from iOS8, there is great extension to UIView called UIVisualEffectView.

There are some links to follow that will give you step by step implementation of that masterpiece:

- http://applidium.com/en/news/mastering_blur_and_vibrancy_with_iOS_8/
- http://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial

Of course, this is only for iOS8, so it might not be usable for you, but I am placing it for others that will search for similar solution.

Comment: Thank you Jiri, next time I will look at this !

Answer (score 0):

I've found : Value have to be inferior to 20 and I reorder some code.

code :

```
UIImageView * blurredArea = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
blurredArea.alpha = 0;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage * snapshot =UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter * filter = [[GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter alloc] init];
filter.blurRadiusInPixels = 12;
UIImage * blurred = [filter imageByFilteringImage: snapshot];
blurredArea.image = blurred;


[blurredArea addSubview:_frameForLogoAnimation];
```

Results look great !

Answer (score 0):

i hope it helps..

if you wants to apply fix value than you can change the value of blurRadiusInPixels in GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter.m file as per your requirement..